# Activity Load Time Calculate

Tags: android, performance

i will use google analytics user timing api [1](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v2/usertimings) and i want to find load time when activity loaded. How to do this? is there any way?

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Check out android's [Traceview](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-tracing.html) Viewer